# Pipe crunch word output into python script

Tags: python

Using `crunch`, I am creating a wordlist. I want to pipe the word generated from the wordlist in realtime into a python script. Here is what I tried:

```
crunch 1 3 | sudo python3 save.py
```

And inside of `save.py` I used `sys` to accept arguments:

```
import sys
f = open("f.txt", "a")
f.write("{}".format(sys.argv[1]))
f.close()
```

I had intended for the output of `crunch` to be piped into this, and written to f.txt, however I got no error message. I do believe I am using the wrong module and piping does not pass arguments into py. Is there a module I should use instead, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping will pass a program's stdout to the next program's stdin. Stdin and sys.argv *are not the same*. Stdin is the standard input file stream comes from the system buffer (usually from user input or another program), while argv is the environment arguments come from the command line. To read from stdin, you should use `sys.stdin.readlines()`. Here is an example.

```
import sys
f = open("f.txt", "a")
for line in sys.stdin:
    f.write("{}".format(line))
f.close()
```

Comment: It seems this awaits the entire output of crunch and saves it as a list instead, not in realtime.

Comment: @xerp152 The `sys.stdin.readlines()` will return a list with splitted stdin in it. I did't try it with `f.write`. A more formal way is using for loop. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I asked for.